# failed to execute mongo like query

Tags: mongodb

This is my mongo query and I'm passing it dynamically but its returning all data, 
I'm passing in postman body parameters as `keyup[processor]` and value as 62, so I need that my query should return all data which has 62 in it, but I'm getting all data.

Please do guide me with this mongo query

```
if(req.body.keyup) {
    for(var i in req.body.keyup) {
    var keyValue = (req.body.keyup[i] === '.' || isNaN(req.body.keyup[i])) ? 999999 : req.body.keyup[i];
        if(i === 'price') {
             match['$and'].push({
                    [i] : +keyValue
                });
        } else if (!findQuery[i]) {
                if (excludeOption.indexOf(i) !== -1) {
                    if (req.body.keyup[i] === 'blank') {
                        findQuery[i] = {
                            '$in' : [null]
                        };
                    } else {
                        findQuery[i] = +keyValue;
                        console.log('line 74',findQuery)
                    }
                } else {
                    if (req.body.keyup[i] === 'blank') {
                        findQuery[i] = {
                            '$in' : [null, 'none', 'None', '', ' ', '-']
                        };
                    } else {
                        findQuery[i] = {
                            '$regex' :   `\\${req.body.keyup[i]}`
                        };
                        console.log('##############')
                    }
                }
```

I'm getting this on console

```
{ processor: { '$regex': '\\6' } }
```

when I run this raw query in mongo I'm getting the output correct

Comment: Unless you post more details: "what you have tried so far, your research effort, your data set, your expected result, what error you're observing etc..", there's nothing much we can do.

Comment: Add some debugging and check you actually have what you think you have. Also that's going to put a leading "literal" slash before the input, so I'm pretty sure that's not what you want. Anyhow, when you ask a question you need to [provide a sample to prove your case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have posted my code which I'm running

Comment: Did you read the "mimimal" part in the link provided? No? `console.log()` your input for `req.body.keyup`, and do the same for the constructed query of `findQuery`. Look at them and see if they have the output you expect or not. If not, then you ask the question about that "little piece of code" that you don't quite understand.